# Convert a Java object to interface via J/Link

Tags: chemistry, java

I'm trying to use a Java library called [CDK](https://cdk.github.io/) with Mathematica's J/Link.

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> $jar];
LoadJavaClass["org.openscience.cdk.silent.SilentChemObjectBuilder"];
sp = JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.smiles.SmilesParser", 
SilentChemObjectBuilder`getInstance[]];
vabcVolume = JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.geometry.volume.VABCVolume"];
atom = sp@parseSmiles["C"]
```

This short code is the Java equivalent to:

```java
SmilesParser   sp  = new
SmilesParser(SilentChemObjectBuilder.getInstance());
IAtomContainer m   = sp.parseSmiles("C");
```

As you can see, I need to convert the `SmilesParser` object to `IAtomContainer` object. In Java, the compiler will do it for me. But I guess Mathematica can't do it automatically. Can someone tell me how I can get an `IAtomContainer` object (this is an Interface object, not class object) in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same confusion when first interacting with java (using the exact same library) - all the functions I want to use take an [`IAtomContainer`](https://cdk.github.io/cdk/2.1/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/interfaces/IAtomContainer.html) as their input, but I can only seem to make [`AtomContainer`](https://cdk.github.io/cdk/2.1/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/AtomContainer.html) objects.

The answers to this question, ["Can we instantiate an interface in Java 8?"](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-instantiate-an-interface-in-Java-8) are relevant here.  Particularly,

> The quick answer would be “No”. you can never instantiate a interface in java however, you can refer to an object that implements an interface by the type of the interface.

For instance, [here](https://cdk.github.io/cdk/2.1/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/tools/manipulator/MolecularFormulaManipulator.html#getAtomContainer-java.lang.String-org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IChemObjectBuilder-) is a static method that takes a molecular formula string and returns an `IAtomContainer`:

```
LoadJavaClass["org.openscience.cdk.tools.manipulator.MolecularFormulaManipulator"];
ac = MolecularFormulaManipulator`getAtomContainer[
  "C2H4", 
  DefaultChemObjectBuilder`getInstance[]
]

(* «JavaObject[org.openscience.cdk.AtomContainer]» *)
```

The method actually returns an `AtomContainer`: a concrete class that implements the interface `IAtomContainer`.

Just to be clear - the molecule generated from the formula string is just a collection of atoms, with no bond information:

```
In[12]:= ac@getBondCount[]

Out[12]= 0
```

I can't speak to why the `VABCVolume` descriptor is complaining, but it isn't due to feeding it the wrong type of argument:

```
sp = JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.smiles.SmilesParser", getInstance[]];
atom = sp @ parseSmiles @ "C";
LoadJavaClass @ "org.openscience.cdk.geometry.volume.VABCVolume";
VABCVolume`calculate @ atom 


During evaluation of In[23]:= Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: org.openscience.cdk.exception.NoSuchAtomTypeException: The AtomType null could not be found
    at org.openscience.cdk.config.AtomTypeFactory.getAtomType(AtomTypeFactory.java:268)
    at org.openscience.cdk.geometry.volume.VABCVolume.calculate(VABCVolume.java:96).

Out[24]= $Failed
```