# Computing the surface area and volume of molecules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry, mesh, chemistry

Here is a somewhat difficult problem I've had for a long while.

[Space-filling models of molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_model) can be easily generated by `ChemicalData[]`, `Import[]` with an appropriate file, or the new `MoleculePlot3D[]` functionality in version 12. For instance,

```
m1 = MoleculePlot3D[Entity["Chemical", "Phenacetin"], PlotTheme -> "Spacefilling"]
```

[image: spacefilling model of phenacetin]

or in older versions,

```
m2 = ChemicalData["Phenacetin", "SpaceFillingMoleculePlot"]
```

[image: spacefilling model of phenacetin]

(Before I proceed further, let me make a warning for people doing comparisons on older systems: the new system uses ångström units, while the old method uses picometer units, with the conversion $1 \ \mathrm{\unicode{x212B}} = 100 \ \mathrm{pm}$. You can see this by evaluating `` Charting`get3DPlotRange[] `` on both plots.)

Now, apart from display purposes, the space-filling model can also be used to compute the so-called *van der Waals area* and *van der Waals volume* of the molecule, where the molecule is treated as a collection of rigid spheres. A simple way to generate the associated van der Waals region would be something like

```
vdwmol = RegionUnion @@ (Ball @@@ Cases[Normal[m1], _Sphere, ∞]);
```

In version 12 (whose online version I am using), one can then use

```
{Quantity[Area[RegionBoundary[vdwmol]], "Angstroms"^2],
 Quantity[Volume[vdwmol], "Angstroms"^3]}
   {Quantity[209.076, ("Angstroms")^2], Quantity[170.445, ("Angstroms")^3]}
```

(replace `"Angstroms"` with `"Picometers"` if you used `m2` instead) to compute the surface area and volume, but this facility is not entirely available in older versions. For example, the area computation will not work in version 11, and none of these methods work in the much older versions that do not have region/mesh functionality. Apart from this, having alternative methods available would be a useful way to check if one is getting reasonable results.

> What are (relatively) *quick* and (reasonably) *accurate* methods to compute the van der Waals area and volume of a given molecule?

Here, "quick" can be e.g. "won't take more than $2$ minutes", and "accurate" would be $\approx 4$ digits of accuracy.

One possibility would be to perform a preliminary discretization via `(Boundary)DiscretizeRegion[]` before using `Area[]`/`Volume[]`, but this moves the difficulty to the discretization step itself, and thus one must come up with a quick way to discretize the molecule. (Nevertheless, the `(Boundary)MeshRegion[]` object thus produced would be a useful object on its own, so methods for quickly producing van der Waals meshes are quite welcome.)

Otherwise, one has to use `NIntegrate[]`. For example, you can compute the volume like so:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[Or @@ Cases[Normal[m1],
                             Sphere[c_, r_] :> Norm[{x, y, z} - c] < r, ∞]],
           {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]
   170.29
```

but computing the surface area with `NIntegrate[]` is not terribly straightforward.

Of course, other methods for computing the van der Waals area and volume based on the output of `MoleculePlot3D[]` (or equivalent functions) would be welcome.

If one wants to test a proposed method on molecules of varying complexity, I would suggest the following `ChemicalData[]` entries: `{"Ethylene", "Adamantane", "Mirex", "Phenacetin", "Caffeine", "Estrone", "Erythromycin"}`

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) Is the data MMA uses to create those space filling models intended to accurately represent their VDW volumes, as opposed to merely being sufficient to create reasonable visualizations? (2) Have you compared the values generated by your code to the best available estimates of VDW volumes? [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo034808o) is a bit old, but might provide a starting point. [It provides a table showing VDW volumes calculated with their fast, simplified method (col D), and with the TSAR molecular modeling software (col E).]

Comment: 1. Indeed, I am making the tacit assumption that the coordinates are "sensible" (e.g. they are the coordinates of an appropriate molecular conformer), and that the van der Waals radii are correct (cursory checking seems to indicate that they are using the classical [Bondi](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100785a001) values), so that in the abstract, this is a problem of finding the surface area and volume of a collection of balls.

Comment: 2. I've seen that paper you refer to, but the problem is now shifted to detecting/counting rings and aromaticity in a given molecule, which does not look straightforward to do especially in older *Mathematica* versions.

Answer (score 14):

I can offer a solution by discretization to `ElementMesh` with external meshing software [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/). Currently it produces better quality mesh on curved surfaces that built-in methods. We need packages [GmshLink](https://github.com/c3m-labs/GmshLink), [ImportMesh](https://github.com/c3m-labs/ImportMesh) and [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools).

```
Needs["GmshLink`"]
(*Set your path to Gmsh executable.*)
$GmshDirectory = "my_path_to_current_release\\gmsh-4.4.1-Windows64";
```

OP's example for molecule and extracted geometric region (`RegionUnion` of `Ball`s).

```
m1 = MoleculePlot3D[Entity["Chemical", "Phenacetin"], PlotTheme -> "Spacefilling"]
vdwmol = RegionUnion @@ (Ball @@@ Cases[Normal[m1], _Sphere, ∞]);
```

Create ElementMesh object from symbolic region. One needs to play around with different options of `GmshGenerator`, especially `MaxCellMeasure` to control density of mesh and therefore accuracy of computed volume and surface. Disabling `"OptimizeQuality"` makes discretization procedure a little faster.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[
  vdwmol,
  "ElementMeshGenerator" -> {GmshGenerator,
    "OptimizeQuality" -> True,
    "GmshAlgorithm" -> "MeshAdapt",
    "MeshOrder" -> 2,
    MaxCellMeasure -> 0.25
    }
  ]

(* ElementMesh[{{-6.29722, 5.70905}, {-3.2177, 3.75228}, {-3.6796, 
   4.2785}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 47739 ">"]}] *)

mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements",
  "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue
  ]]
```

[image: mesh]

```
Histogram[Flatten@mesh["Quality"], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image: quality]

MeshTools package contains functions for calculation of `ElementMesh` volume and surface.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]

Total@Flatten@MeshElementMeasure[mesh]
(* 171.261 *)

Total@Flatten@BoundaryElementMeasure[mesh]
(* 215.234 *)
```

This example took about 30 seconds on my computer and discretization time is heavily affected by `MaxCellMeasure`. One could also use other meshing software and import is result as `ElementMesh` object.

Comment: This looks nice; I'll try this out once I get my computer back.

Answer (score 13):

The paper [Fast Calculation of van der Waals Volume as a Sum of Atomic and Bond Contributions and Its Application to Drug Compounds](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo034808o), pointed out by [theorist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45215/theorist) gives an approximate formula for the molecular volume as

$$
V_{\mathrm{vdW}} = \sum \mathrm{all\: atom\: contributions} - 5.92 N_\mathrm{B} - 14.7 R_\mathrm{A} - 3.8 R_\mathrm{NA}
$$

where $N_\mathrm{B}$ is the number of bonds, $R_\mathrm{A}$ the number of aromatic rings, and $R_\mathrm{NA}$ the number of nonaromatic rings.

```
vdwSurfaceArea[mol_ ? MoleculeQ] := Module[
    {atomRadii, atomContributions, nb, ra, rna},
    atomRadii = AtomList[
        mol, All, EntityProperty["Element", "VanDerWaalsRadius"]
    ];
    If[MemberQ[atomRadii, _Missing],
        Return[Missing @ "VDWRadiusMissing", Module]
    ];
    atomRadii = UnitConvert[atomRadii, "Angstroms"];
    atomContributions = N @ Total[(4 / 3) * Pi * atomRadii^3];
    nb = BondCount[mol];
    ra = mol["AromaticRingCount"];
    rna = mol["AliphaticRingCount"];
    atomContributions - Quantity[5.92 nb + 14.7 ra + 3.8 rna, "Angstroms" ^ 3];
]
```

The results match *reasonably* closely with those in the supporting info for the linked paper. For the molecule in [Pinti's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206297/9490) you get something very close to the mesh volume:

```
In[73]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 vdwSurfaceArea[Molecule["N-(4-ethoxyphenyl)acetamide"]]]

Out[73]= {0.01516, Quantity[176.291, ("Angstroms")^3]}
```

Comment: This is certainly a great solution for version 12; I do wonder how hard this would be to do in older versions...

Comment: Before the version 12 functions were added, I used the CDK java library quite a bit. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182304/9490) is an example using it from through *JLink*.  And looking [here](https://github.com/cdk/cdk/blob/master/descriptor/qsarmolecular/src/main/java/org/openscience/cdk/qsar/descriptors/molecular/SmallRingDescriptor.java) I see that they do have `"nAromRings"` and `"nSmallRings"` descriptors that you could use to construct the above function.

Answer (score 6):

The method used in Jason's answer, as noted, requires version 12. For those in earlier versions who are unable or unwilling to install cheminformatics toolboxes like [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/), [ChEMBL Beaker](https://github.com/mnowotka/chembl_beaker) (see also the [associated paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/challe5020444)) provides an API that can be used to compute the ring counts required by the underlying formula, which is used in the code that follows:

```
vdwVolume[s_] := Module[{mol, molString, raw},
   mol = Table[ChemicalData[s, p],
               {p, {"VertexTypes", "EdgeRules", "EdgeTypes", "AtomPositions"}}]; 
   molString =
   ExportString[Thread[{"VertexTypes", "EdgeRules", "EdgeTypes", "VertexCoordinates"} -> 
                       MapAt[QuantityMagnitude, mol, 4]], {"MOL", "Rules"}];
   raw = URLExecute["https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/api/utils/descriptors", {}, 
                    "RawJSON", Method -> "POST", "Headers" -> {"Expect" -> ""}, 
                    "Body" -> molString];
   UnitConvert[Total[Times @@@ MapAt[(4/3 π ElementData[#, "VanDerWaalsRadius"]^3) &, 
                                     Tally[mol[[1]]], {All, 1}]] - 
               Quantity[{3.8, 14.7} .
                        First[Lookup[raw, {"NumAliphaticRings", "NumAromaticRings"}]] + 
                        5.92 Length[mol[[2]]], "Angstroms"^3], "Angstroms"^3]]
```

I have omitted error checking/trapping from this code to keep it short; for actual applications, you should add in the necessary safeguards. Additionally, in version 11, one should instead use `HTTPRequest[]` in `URLExecute[]`.

For example,

```
QuantityMagnitude[vdwVolume /@ {"Ethylene", "Adamantane", "Mirex", "Phenacetin",
                                "Caffeine", "Estrone", "Erythromycin"}]
   {40.512, 140.647, 298.467, 176.291, 151.433, 266.593, 731.435}
```

(If you want to use this method directly on MOL files, you can replace the first two assignments with something like `molString = Import["fileName.mol", "Text"]; mol = ImportString[molString, {"MOL", {"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}];`.)